# Compressed Sensing

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, optimization

I really would like to know more about compressed sensing. I am currently a PhD student working on array signal processing. The field of compressed sensing is super attractive to my opinion, but i really think it might waste my time in case i do not know where to start. I am saying that because there is a very large literature on the topic. If anyone out there is an expert or, at the least, knows about the domain, please help me with some advices.

Thank you so very much.

Comment: I'm a grad student in an unrelated field of math, but there are some people in my department who have done their dissertation partially in compressed sensing. They have told me that it it is starting to die off, at least in terms of connection to applications. Mathematicians proved a bunch of nice theorems about certain classes of compressive sensing techniques, and then practitioners found that they can't actually implement those classes of techniques, because the way that they ask for samples is "too random".

Comment: (Cont.) Meanwhile the theorems that they can prove about more structured sampling techniques are only modest improvements at best over more conventional techniques.

Comment: @Ian Wow i never knew that, thanks for letting me know. 
What do you think might find application in array signal processing other than compressed sensing then? P.S: My question might be a bit wrong to ask.